# Task Scheduler: run task each hour from the current moment

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, scheduled-tasks

Here is the problem: I need to create scheduled task which will be executed each hour right from the moment it will be installed. And then it must be started each time user log in.

So far so good. Using [examples from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I've created a task based on ILogonTrigger, I've set repetition to one hour and thats ok. After relogin or reboot task starts perfectly - that what I need. But I don't want user to reboot or relogin right now.

So the question is: how to make that countdown from the current moment? I understand that I can force to run the registered task - but thats what I want to avoid, I want to start it hour later, and then again, and again, etc...

One solution I can imagine right now is to create logon task without repetition and start it with some delay. And each time it executes run it again with delay. But it is a bad solution to me. May be I'm missing something?

Oh. And all that must be compatible with the first version of Task Scheduler (i.e. TASK_COMPATIBILITY_V1 setting is set). But I can live without it :)

Thanks for your advices if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've managed how to do almost I want by myself.

For the Task Scheduler 2.0 it can be done by assigning another trigger to task: IRegistrationTask. If TASK_COMPATIBILITY_V1 setting will be set that trigger just wouldn't be assigned.

For Windows XP I've just created IDailyTrigger with start boundary set to 00:05. That's not exactly  what I need, but it works pretty well.